# Como utilizar Cookies no Internet Explorer?

Tags: php, internet-explorer

Estou tentando armazenar cookies para uma aplicação que desenvolvi em PHP e notei que no Internet Explorer meus cookies não estão sendo armazenados (ou estão expirando logo após sua criação).
No meu código eu defini os Cookies desta maneira:

```
setcookie("login", $login_confirmacao, time() + 3600, "/");
setcookie("senha", $senha_confirmacao, time() + 3600, "/");
```

Notei que ao desabilitar esta função o navegador armazenou os Cookies:

> [ ] Bloquear cookies de terceiros que não tenham uma política de privacidade compacta.

Como posso definir essa "Política de privacidade compacta" ? ou como faço para utilizar cookies no IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O IE não confia em cookies vindos de iframes que não tenham política de privacidade(p3p).

Então você teria de fazer um arquivo XML que identifica sua política de privacidade. Essa seria a versão compacta. Pra fazer certinho você teria de criar uma versão completa também, mas o única referência que encontrei são pra geradores pagos.

Referência: http://www.w3.org/P3P/details.html

Exemplo:

```
<META>
  <POLICY-REFERENCES>
    <POLICY-REF about="/url-da-politica-de-privacidade/p3p.xml">
      <INCLUDE>/</INCLUDE>
      <COOKIE-INCLUDE/>
    </POLICY-REF>
  </POLICY-REFERENCES>
</META>
```

Dentro da tag INCLUDE você coloca que partes do seu site essa política de privacidade abrangem no caso "/" é tudo.

Depois, no PHP você teria de colocar os headers de acordo com sua política de privacidade, se você esta só testando pode apenas usar os headers, mas se for colocar em produção deve fazer os outros passos:

Exemplo:

```
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');
```

Cada acrônimo desses representa um tipo de comportamento em relação à privacidade do usuário por parte do seu site.

Uma lista completa: http://www.p3pwriter.com/LRN_111.asp

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação Erik.

Answer (score 2):

Caso deseje manipular cookies no IE com JavaScript, uma boa abordagem seria utilizar a lib: **[JqueryCookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)**

O uso em si é bastante simples:

**Armazenar:** `$.cookie('variavel_nome', 'valor');`

**Ler:** `$.cookie('variavel_nome');`

**Deletar:** `$.removeCookie('variavel_nome');`

Comment: Obrigado Gustavo, vou tentar ;)

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi sua pergunta mas se você tiver querendo adicionar um *cookie*, isso deve funcionar:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
letterTable='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm';
function rot13(str) {
 var outStr='';
 for (var k=0;k<str.length;k++) {
  var ch=str.charAt(k);
  var ix=letterTable.indexOf(ch);
  outStr+= (ix==-1) ? ch : letterTable.charAt(ix+13) ;
 }
 return outStr;
}

function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
 var today = new Date();
 var expire = new Date();
 if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
 expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
                 + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}
//-->
</script>

<pre>
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
 var today = new Date();
 var expire = new Date();
 if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
 expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
                 + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}
</pre>
```

Formulario:

```
<form name="setCookie">
<table border=0 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3>
<tr><td>Nome do Cookie:&nbsp;
</td><td><input name=t1 type=text size=20 value="NomeDocookie">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Valor do Cookie:&nbsp;
</td><td><input name=t2 type=text size=20 value="Valor Do Cookie">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Deve expirar em:&nbsp;
</td><td><input name=t3 type=text size=3 value="5"> Dias de hoje
</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input name=b1 type=button value="Set Cookie"
onClick="SetCookie('__Teste__',rot13(this.form.t1.value,this.form.t3.value));
SetCookie(this.form.t1.value,this.form.t2.value,this.form.t3.value);">
</td></tr></table>
</form>
```

Comment: Legal. É válido usar a resposta **também** para pedir por mais informações para o autor, caso você esteja disposto editá-la depois para atualizar com as informações adicionais. Mas logo você poderá comentar também.